# Angular 2+ launch observable function with interval inside switchMap

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => {
            this.token = params['token'];
            return this.signUpService.provisioningTenant(this.token);
         })
        .subscribe(...);
```

And it works fine for me.

But I want to execute `this.signUpService.provisioningTenant(this.token)` while one condition isn't true.

And I try the following:

```
this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => {
        this.token = params['token'];
        return Observable
                   .interval(5000)
                   .takeWhile(() => !this.isDnsCreated)
                   .pipe(this.signUpService.provisioningTenant(this.token));
     }).subscribe(...);
```

But see error `any supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target...`.

How can I resolve my issue? Maybe my code isn't correct. How should I rewrite it to execute my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me:

```
Observable
    .interval(5000)
    .takeWhile(() => !this.isCompleted)
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => {
                this.token = params['token'];

                return this.service.check(this.token);
            })
            .subscribe(...);
    });
```